# can i run java code on arduino hardware (without using port communication)?

Tags: java, arduino

Ok, i'm trying to make a simple robot on arduino, but i'm not so good at c++ and i have a short deadline to make it work.

Would be much better if the board could run java code on its own hardware

Is it possible??

(Also, i'm using arduino atmega 2560 with windows on my computer)

Comment: There is at least one virtual machine for AVRs.

http://haiku-vm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes you  do it with java too because one of my friend have been doing but using c++ or python will ease your work instead.

Comment: The entire Arduino world is build for people who are not very good at programming. The necessary C++ knowledge to develop for Arduino is close to zero. As already mentioned it is possible, but it doesn't make any sense. Especially if you have limited time. The time to somehow make this work on an Arduino is most likely a lot more than to simply implement it in C++.